# Rmarkdown Html with a4 size

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I'm new using Rmarkdown. Is there one way to create HTML document with A4 size for all pages?

I don't find anything about it.

Thanks

Comment: "HTML document" and "A4 size" seem contradictory to me. I'm likely confused, but can you show me an HTML document that is sized for letter, A4, or something related? (Somewhat related could be Yihue's and Romain's new [`pagedown`](https://github.com/rstudio/pagedown) package, still in development.)

Comment: @r2evans yes It seem contradictory... but is there one way to show like "A4 size", like If you have a book.

Comment: Show me an html page that is "sized". At the moment, the only ones I've heard of are completely done in javascript pagination (as in `pagedown`), suggesting that it is a singular implementation for that js engine, and therefore not yet an rmarkdown thing.

Comment: Really, though, look at `pagedown`, it alleges to support pagination and therefore page-sizes in an HTML document. It already supports several layout options.

Comment: @r2evans Yes I saw it. I think It's perfect for me but I can see example code for letter.

Comment: @r2evans html_letter. I can't see example code.

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/pagedown/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/html-letter/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd

Comment: Maybe you want to be rendering to PDF instead. HTML is designed for the web, i.e. not print, so there generally aren't page sizes or pages associated with an HTML document. Try printing a web page in your browser, and see that the page size and setup are probably arbitrary, rather than set by some characteristics of the page itself

Comment: @camille I would like to use interactive graph in rmarkdown (plotly). I would like my output will be PDF but Ithink It can't.

Comment: PDFs are static documents, so something like Plotly, which runs on Javascript, won't be interactive. But it's still unclear what bearing page size would have on an HTML document, since it's intended to be on the web, and web pages don't really have "page" sizes

Comment: @camille Yes It is strange but I would like It seems like paper. Pagedown is solution but I can't use rmarkdown code